# How to implement keystroke logging by java

Tags: java, keylistener, keylogger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you record keystrokes when operating on another window in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010657/how-do-you-record-keystrokes-when-operating-on-another-window-in-java)

Try to get all keystroke on the OS. any ideas?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Did you want to log key strokes for you own app or for the OS?

Comment: @MadProgrammer all keystroke on the OS.

Comment: @Borgleader I have not try anything. Just curious how to implement it.

Answer (score -2):

Yeah possibly u should get the keystrokes of the users through the use of `currentTimeMillis` method or so in java in any of the `keyPressed()` or `keyReleased()` methods in java.Then save those time recordings in any variable get the time difference and then compare it with the keystrokes stored in database with a particular threshold.It should work then.During the recording phase make the user type the intended filed 5-6 times, take the keystrokes recording of the user and then save its mean in the database and compare it with the current keystrokes of the user while he tries to log in.